# What main factors/features explain the high price of most industrial computer vision hardware?

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, sensors, robotics, depth

I am a student who is currently working on a computer science project that will require soon computer vision and more specifically stereoscopy (for depth detection). I am now looking for a great camera to do the job and I found several interesting options:

1- A custom built set of two cheap cameras (i.e. webcam);

2- The old, classic, economic and proven Kinect;

3- Specialized stereo sensors.

I found a couple months ago this sensor: https://duo3d.com/product/duo-mini-lv1

I tought it was interesting because it is small, stereoscopic and brand new (encouraging a fresh USA company). However, if we take apart the additional APIs that come with it, I just don't understand why you would buy this when a Kinect (or "cheap" cameras) are at least 4-5 times less expensive and still have great if not better specifications.

Same applies for this one: http://www.ptgrey.com/bumblebee2-firewire-stereo-vision-camera-systems

Can someone please explain to me why I would need such a device and if not, why they are needed for some?

Comment: Not really a programming question.  Better fit for signal processing or robotics stack exchange.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was asking myself whether or not I should post here. I saw a couple of questions about hardware with the 'sensor' tag so I gave it a try.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you want a "real" stereo camera as opposed to a pair of usb webcams is synchronization. Cameras like the bumblebee have hardware triggering, which takes the two images with virtually no delay in between. With the webcams you will always have a noticeable delay between the two shots. This may be ok if you are looking at a static scene or at a scene where things are moving slowly. But if you want to have a stereo camera on a mobile robot, you will need good synchronization.

Kinect is great. However, a good stereo pair of cameras has a couple of serious advantages. One is that Kinect will not work outdoors during the day. The bright sun will interfere with the infra-red camera that Kinect uses for depth estimation. Also Kinect has a fairly short range of a few meters. You can get 3D information at much larger distances with a stereo pair by increasing the baseline.

Comment: What about the Kinect?

Answer (score 3):

In computer vision, we always want an ideal stereo camera such as no skewness on pixels, perfectly matched, aligned, identical cameras and so on. The cameras must supply enough images per seconds, because some of the algorithms uses temporal information that requires high fps to approximate the continuous motion. The lens is also an important part which may be so expensive. Additionally, the hardware suppliers generally provide an SDK. Creating an SDK is adding them extra value, because we always want to care what is important for us such as algorithms. Preparing the required software in order to connect the cameras to PC or any other boards may waste our time.

Kinect allows researchers to get depth information easily with a really good price; however, I agree with Dima that it's just for indoor applications and Kinect depth data has some holes which are generally required to be filled.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Dima already pointed out: The cameras that you have listed both only give you the raw image data. If you are interested in the depth data, you will have to compute them yourself which can be very resource demanding and hard to do in real-time.

I currently know of one hardware system which does that for you in real-time:
http://nerian.com/products/sp1-stereo-vision/

But I don't think that this would be cheap either, and you would have to buy that on-top of the industrial cameras. So, if you are looking for a cheap solution, you should go with the Kinnect.